# Deleted the .project file in the eclipse workspace

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-mars

I had a problem with eclipse (mars) on my android project so I looked it up and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056987/android-sdk-content-loader-at-0-and-nothing-works) question, I followed the first answer and they made me delete the .project file `(which is located in workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.safetable)` when I tried to paste it later it was gone. Now I'm getting a lot of errors in eclipse when I try to do stuff like run the project. Is there any way to recover it? Or is there a duplicate I can download from somewhere?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Just reimport the project folder.. File > new > Android > Existing Android COde into wor. . ..

Comment: You should provide the errors you are receiving in your question

Comment: Try the solution suggest by @sheychan, it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i were you i would upgrade to android studio.

You can try to import your broken project and maybe android studio will fix it for you. Since android studio works with Gradle builds it might fix just that.

Comment: I used to use it, but my project uses maven and I don't think it's compatible for android studio, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: there is a plugin now standard in android studio for Maven integration. i'm not familiar with Maven so i would have no idea if it works or not. but you can always try to take a shot ? how far are you in your project ? would you consider manually migrating ?

Comment: can you give me a link to the plugin?

Comment: sorry i was eating.
If you go to android studio > search (top right) > (actions) plugins > Maven integration

Comment: I haven't used android studio for a while, and when I opened it I got a very long list of errors, should I delete it and reinstall it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576602/does-android-studio-support-maven
Something usefull for you here?