# Importing Maven project in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio

I am new to Android development. I am trying to open Android project build by using maven into android studio. But I am unable to open, I can see only code. I can't see maven option on the right side of Android Studio as shown in picture:

[image: picure]

I am using Android Studio 2.1.2. and attached screenshot is of lower version 1.5. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16576602/does-android-studio-support-maven) I know that Android Studio support maven but I can't see mvn option in add new configuration.